# The pstrServer parameter of CInternetSession::GetFtpConnection

Tags: visual-c++, browser, mfc, ftp

I am recently building a simple web browser just to test my internet skills. I came across the `GetFtpConnection` method of class `CInternetSession`, and I don't know how to "fill in" the `pstrServer` parameter, which indicates the FTP server name. I tried to Google it out, but I can't find any useful information. Can you tell me what is a server name? Is it something like **www.google.com**? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP protocol is described in many places, including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol). An example from the linked page shows the format of an FTP URL:

[image]

In the above example, the `<host>` portion is what is meant by the "server" in the [`GetFtpConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzey6f41%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function.

You can also see where the other parameters, like `user`, `password` and `port number` map.

The following code example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzey6f41%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) shows how the function is used:

[image: msdn]

Comment: Is the `pstrServer` parameter in method `GetHttpConnection` similar to this one in `GetFtpConnection`?

Comment: @VictorPrograss yes, it's a similar thing, it identifies a server, either as an IP address or as name that can be looked up via DNS to get an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

`ptrServer` is the DNS name of the server - e.g. `www.google.com`, `ftp.microsoft.com` or its IP address - e.g. `74.125.131.105`.